# How to use phpseclib in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpseclib

I placed the `phpseclib` files in my `application/third_party` folder, I have included the path in my controller as shown below

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'third_party/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php');
```

But I cannot create an **instance** of that class. Getting an error as

> class ssh2 not found

What's the most appropriate way to use `phpseclib`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a lot of research, I finally found my problem. The problem was - i didn't add include the path after setting the set_include_path. Here is what I did-
1. I placed phpseclib files in my application/third_party folder.
2. In my controller, I set the include path as `set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');`
3. After setting the path, I included the path as `include_once(APPPATH.'third_party/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php');`
4. Now I can create my instance as `$sftp = new Net_SFTP('your-host');`
5. And connect my server as `$sftp->login('user-name', 'password')`

Answer (score 0):

On github.com there are two branches (in addition to the master branch) - 1.0 and 2.0. 2.0 is namespaced so to call that you'd need to do \phpseclib\Net\SSH2.

If you downloaded the zip file from phpseclib.sourceforge.net then you're running the 1.0 branch. If that's what you're running you'll need to update the include path. eg.

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');
```

If you're running the 2.0 branch (or master branch) you'll need to use an auto loader. Example:

```
<?php
// https://raw.githubusercontent.com/composer/composer/master/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassLoader.php

include('autoloader.php');

$loader = new \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader();
$loader->addPsr4('phpseclib\\', __DIR__.'/phpseclib');
$loader->register();

use \phpseclib\Crypt\RSA;

$rsa = new RSA();
```

Comment: I am running the 1.0 branch and I did set the include path like you did but still when I try to create an instance like 'new Net_SSH2('host')', I am getting the error like Class 'Net_SSH2' not found. How can i create an instance of the class if I'm running  1.0 branch?

Comment: @RakibIbnaHamid - Did you install the 1.0 branch using Composer? If not then you'd need to manually include the files. eg. `include('Net/SSH2.php');`